# Field Name vs Relationship Name

Tags: custom-field, relationships, sobject, fields

For the custom (reference) fields the relationship name is the same as field name, the only difference is that relationship name ends with **__r** and field name with **__c**

Example :

- field name : *Account__c*
- relationship name : *Account__r*

What is the logic for the standard fields & relationships ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's different for Accounts, since they have a hierarchy:

1. ParentId will give you the Id
2. Parent.Name Will return the parents
   name.

In general it would be

```
SELECT AccountId, Account.Name FROM Contact
```

As [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)

Comment: So for standard fields the field name looks like *somethingId* and the relationship name like *something*? example : OwnerId, Owner

Comment: @benahm Yes, you are right!